SearchBar Jetpack Compose recompose too much times, is it normal?
I have SearchBar with horizontal padding depend on active status.
Every time the active status changes, the composable recomposes 5-6 times, is it normal?
Can I improve performance this SearchBar?
My example code:
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun LimitRecomposeSearchBar(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    var query by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    val onQueryChange: (String) -> Unit = {
        query = it
    }
    val onSearch: (String) -> Unit = {}

    var active by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val onActiveChange: (Boolean) -> Unit = {
        active = it
    }

    val paddingAnimation by animateDpAsState(
        if (active) 0.dp else 16.dp,
        label = "paddingAnimation"
    )

    Column(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        SearchBar(
            query = query,
            onQueryChange = onQueryChange,
            onSearch = onSearch,
            active = active,
            onActiveChange = onActiveChange,
            modifier = modifier
                .widthIn(max = 488.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(horizontal = paddingAnimation),
            leadingIcon = {
                Icon(
                    painterResource(R.drawable.ic_search),
                    stringResource(R.string.button_search)
                )
            },
            placeholder = {
                Text(stringResource(R.string.placeholder_search))
            },
        ) {
        }
    }
}


